# azure application gateway is not working with 502

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I am following the example here on Azure tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-cli

And at the end when I browser for the IP address I got:

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

Comment: any update in this case?

Comment: yes, it was a mistake. I changed a bit on the tutorial, and configured the backend machines to run on port 8080. So, I had to change the listener.

So, the question is not valid, and I couldn't delete it

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of HTTP 502 Error:** The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502))

So make sure you are not using proxy in client or server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: Application gateway throws 502.

Application gateway throws 502 when the backend VMs/ resource is unavailable.

Step 1: Check the backend health from portal. It shows the current health status of your backend resource. If it is unhealthy, it shows the reason why it is "unhealthy"

- Possible Reason :

  - NSG/UDR blocking the request reaching the resource
  - Backend server responds to with respond codes which is not between (200-399)
  - If it is an end to end SSL , certificate needs to be whitelisted

Step 2: If the backend is healthy, and you still receive 502, make sure the backend is responding to the request sent by Application gateway within 30 seconds(Default value).